# getting input in gui programming

Tags: c, windows, user-interface, input, keyboard

I'm somehow aware of C programming and now I need to program in GUI with C language in codeblock. My project is in:(win32 GUI project). I can make a windows with ok, cancel key, but I want to get input from user in form of char (from keyboard). I want to save it's input and do something on it (for example get a password and check if it's true or not) but I can't find how to do it and what is it's function? A kind of windows which has a bar for getting input of user and save the input in buffer, have ok key to go next window. actually I don't use any library. just include windows.h and stdio.h and noting else.

Comment: You haven't told us which toolkit you are using...

Comment: text box or Such components

Comment: which library you are using  [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) or [wxWidget](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)?

Comment: If you want to use just win API, then it's some hard work with dialog calls and resource templates.  It's way, way, WAY easier with a GUI framework and form designer.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [`EDIT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775458.aspx) window and use that to retrieve input from the user.